# Is Blackberry User-Agent only sent via browser?

Tags: blackberry, user-agent

I would like to ask wheter the User-Agent property in the HTTP request header only sent via browser?

When I send a http/https request from a blackberry application, it seems there is no user-agent contains in the http header.

Thanks very much!

Also, if it is not possible to get the user agent from the request, are we able to get the user agent from Blackberry device?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, according to the Java document (javax.microedition.io 
), it seems that user-agent is not automatically included unless you set it.

> The application is responsible for
>   formatting and requesting that the
>   User-Agent field be included in HTTP
>   requests via the setRequestProperty
>   method in the interface

http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/JSR_271_Mobile_Information_Device_Profile_3_0/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html

Answer (score 3):

No, User-Agent is not sent automatically if you use javax.microedition.io.HttpConnection from within your application.

Instead, use

 `HttpConnection con = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(myURL, 
                                         Connector.READ_WRITE, true);`

con.setRequestProperty(HttpProtocolConstants.HEADER_USER_AGENT, 
                                        "MyBlackberryApplication/1.0");
 ...

If you need information about the device to send along the agent string, all of it (OS version, device etc.) is  accessible via BlackBerry API: look at this class: [net.rim.device.api.system.DeviceInfo](http://www.blackberry.com/developers/docs/4.3.0api/net/rim/device/api/system/DeviceInfo.html)

Answer (score 1):

For unsigned j2me applications you can't set the user-agent and it will always be
UNTRUSTED/1.0

http://www.j2megame.org/j2meapi/JSR_271_Mobile_Information_Device_Profile_3_0/javax/microedition/io/package-summary.html

> This behavior for the Unidentified
>   domain applications is specified in
>   the Mobile Service Architecture (JSR
>   248) specification

Answer (score 0):

Turn the level from untrusted to maximum in WTK-Edit-Preference-Security-Security domain can be helpful to the "untrusted" user-agent problem in http requests.

> For unsigned j2me applications you can't set the user-agent and it will always be UNTRUSTED/1.0